# Python list comprehension with extra variable recorded?

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension

I want to do the following thing with list comprehension, is it possible?:

```
# find the max i + lst[i] in a list, where i is the index and record both the index and the value
lst = [4,3,2,1,1,1]

val, idx = 0,0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] + i > val:
        val = lst[i] + i
        idx = i

# in list comprehension I am only able to find max value, is there a way to find both? 
mx = max([i + lst[i] for i in lst])
```

Comment: That code both has an error (`list[i]` instead of `lst[i]`) and outputs the wrong output (`idx` is `5` instead of `0`). Also `mx` is `5`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will output a tuple of max value and the index where the max value occurs:

```
print(max([(i + n, i) for i, n in enumerate(lst)]))
```

This outputs: `(6, 5)`

Comment: `key=itemgetter(0)` is redundant. Looking at the first element of containers first is the default behavior.